# Fuzzdb detected as Trojans

Tags: web-application, appsec, penetration-test, attacks, fuzzing

I recently downloaded fuzzdb from http://code.google.com/p/fuzzdb/ and my antivirus kept on detecting some of the files as Trojans. I need to know if these files are safe?

[image]

Comment: You're asking us to run a virus scan on some [fuzzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) app? Have you at least read the file paths? Of course they're not safe, you don't know what you're doing. Rare few professional tools are safe in such circumstances. Steer clear and read the manual! It's loaded with nukes! Intentionally!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fuzzdb contains a collection of web backdoor programs which if they were present on a live server would be a good indication that it had been compromised.

This is likely why the A-V tool is reacting to those files.  It is a common issue with penetration testing tools that A-V software regards them as malicious.

However just downloading them is not going to cause your machine to be compromised and as they are JSP/ASP/PHP files, you probably can't execute them by double-clicking them so in the sense of a traditional virus, you likely don't have anything to worry about.

That said code downloaded from the Internet can contain anything, and you should always review code before using it, if you're worried about its provenance.

Comment: @RoryMcCune Thanks for your kind reply. I did not execute those files. As shown in the screenshot my A-V tool detected them as Trojans as soon as I downloaded them to my PC. Sorry for asking this from you again, will it affect my computer?

Comment: @frozenhaart No, they're not viruses so they won't propagate, but you don't want them on your machine either, even less so execute them or worse yet, place them in an externally accessible execution path and someone could use them as backdoors to your system. Safest would be to uninstall / delete your local copy and not touch anything like that until you've familiarized yourself with what they are, what purpose they serve and how to use them safely. This is not something you'd want anywhere near any production machines.